# symfony 5: mapping error in a bidirectional class relation

Tags: class, orm, doctrine, foreign-keys, symfony5

I want a category class which can have a category as its parent.
therefore the class category must take as parent (can be null) itself.
and I want the relation to be two-way so that I can also retrieve the children of a category.
here is my current code:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="id_category_1", columns={"id_cat_parent"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_category", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idCategory;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="denomination", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $denomination;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="ChildrensCategories", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_category", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $categoryParent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, mappedBy="categoryParent", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $ChildrensCategories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ChildrensCategories = new ArrayCollection();
    }



    public function getIdCategory(): ?int
    {
        return $this->idCategory;
    }

    public function getDenomination(): ?string
    {
        return $this->denomination;
    }

    public function setDenomination(string $denomination): self
    {
        $this->denomination = $denomination;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategoryParent(): ?self
    {
        return $this->categoryParent;
    }

    public function setCategoryParent(?self $categoryParent): self
    {
        $this->categoryParent = $categoryParent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|self[]
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategory(self $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories[] = $category;
            $category->setCategoryParent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(self $category): self
    {
        if ($this->categories->removeElement($category)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($category->getCategoryParent() === $this) {
                $category->setCategoryParent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Category[]
     */
    public function getChildrensCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ChildrensCategories;
    }

    public function addChildrensCategory(Category $childrensCategory): self
    {
        if (!$this->ChildrensCategories->contains($childrensCategory)) {
            $this->ChildrensCategories[] = $childrensCategory;
            $childrensCategory->setCategoryParent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeChildrensCategory(Category $childrensCategory): self
    {
        if ($this->ChildrensCategories->removeElement($childrensCategory)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($childrensCategory->getCategoryParent() === $this) {
                $childrensCategory->setCategoryParent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

but symfony gives me an error:
[image]

I don't understand where the error comes from

Thanks for your aid.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
it was just missing an annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="ChildrensCategories", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_cat_parent", referencedColumnName="id_category")
 */
private $categoryParent;
```